# Por qué me salen errores en cualquier arhivo de NestJS, si todo esta correcto? Pd: soy nuevo

Tags: nodejs, typescript, error404, nestjs, devops

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, soy nuevo en NodeJS y estoy usando NestJS, acabo de instalar el framework, pero en cualquier archivo que entro me sale en rojo, como se muestra en la imagen, me ejecuta normal, pero me muestra cada archivo cuando entro a editarlo en rojo, como si tuviera errores.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No sabemos que ide estas usando.. no sabemos que errores recibis.. deberias dar un poco mas de contexto.. porque decis que son errores???

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Buen día, disculpen por no explicarme bien, estoy usando VSC, recién estoy comenzando aprendiendo NodeJS y estoy usando NestJS, al instalar el paquete de NestJS, incluso sin hacerle ninguna modificación, cada que entro a un archivo, me sale en rojo, como si tuviera errores de código como se muestra en la imagen, me ejecuta normal, pero me sale cada archivo en rojo

Comment: Eso solo está marcando errores en el archivo. No podemos saber qué errores son... tienes que abrir el archivo y mirar en qué línea te marca el error. Por la pinta, no tienes bien configurado el entorno y no es capaz de "ver" que está todo correcto, pero sin ver exactamente qué errores tienes, no es posible ayudarte